# How to fix Memory error in Ansible?

Tags: jenkins, ansible

Now i m trying to copy the file from `/Build_Artifacts/build.zip` to `/Build_Artifacts/`. Permission was set to `777` for `/Build_Artifacts/`.

while running the playbook it reports as Memory error!!

`cat deploy.yml`

```
 hosts: "{{host}}" user: soundar tasks:
```

---

```
    - name: copying
      copy: src=/Build_Artifacts/build.zip  dest=/Build_Artifacts/

jenkins@ip-10-0-6-189:~$ sudo ansible-playbook /var/lib/jenkins/deploy.yml --extra-vars "host=Resurgence-Dev"

PLAY [Resurgence-Dev] **********************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [10.0.3.233]

TASK [copying] *****************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: MemoryError
fatal: [10.0.3.233]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
        to retry, use: --limit @/var/lib/jenkins/deploy.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.0.3.233                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ansible has known memory issues while trying to copy large files. For [example](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/5496).
It loads file into RAM and fails if file is large enough.

Use [synchronize](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) module instead. It uses rsync under the hood.

Comment: That link is dead now - [this one](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to mention that for me a similar issue existed when trying to used sbt assembly. My mistake was that I accidentally build it on the cluster e.g. specified the wrong host instead of local. Just wanted to mention this here in case someone makes the same mistake and runs into crazy memory issues ;)